# Django on googleappengine silent model save failure with json_field

Tags: python, django, json, google-app-engine

and thank you for taking the time to read my question.

I have a view that is updating a user's profile. I can retrieve the profile via

```
profile = request.user.get_profile()
```

and modify it. I then call the save method:

```
profile.save()
```

However, I see that the changes are not being saved. My view then redirects the user to another page. In order to verify that this is not happening in the subsequent page load, I reselect the profile, again using get_profile(), and when I call

```
logging.info(profile.__dict__)
```

I see that the changes didn't "take". There are no errors raised, nothing logged.

Here is the definition for the three fields I'm changing:

```
 account = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='', db_index=True)
 token = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, default='')
 profile = JSONField(blank=True, default={})
```

The json should be valid because it is being returned from a service, and I use the same code to create the model in the first place.

There is no custom validation in the model, nothing that I could see that could cause this issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Django caches the result of get_profile().  To see if you are hitting a caching issue, try replacing your calls to get_profile with ORM queries (e.g. MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)).  If that fixes the problem, it's because your second call to get_profile is returning a cached object.

Comment: I already tried that and it didn't help, but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to have bothered everyone! :(

I forgot that I had overridden the save method in the model, and there was a bug in the method that was preventing saves!

Thanks for you time!